# Mocking a module import in pytest

Tags: python, pytest

I am writing a pytest plugin that should test software that's designed to work inside a set of specific environments.

The software I'm writing is run inside a bigger framework, which makes certain Python modules available only when running my Python software inside the framework.

In order to test my software, I'm required to "mock" or fake an entire module (actually, quite a few). I'll need to implement its functionality in some kind of similar-looking way, but my question is how should I make this fake Python module available to my software's code, using a py.test plugin?

For example, let's assume I have the following code in one of my source files:

```
import fwlib

def fw_sum(a, b):
    return fwlib.sum(a, b)
```

However, the `fwlib` module is only made available by the framework I run my software from, and I cannot test inside it.

How would I make sure, from within a pytest plugin, that a module named `fwlib` is already defined in `sys.modules`? Granted, I'll need to implement `fwlib.sum` myself. I'm looking for recommendations on how to do just that.

Answer (score 49, accepted):

<s>pytest provides a fixture for this use-case: [`monkeypatch.syspath_prepend`](https://docs.pytest.org/en/latest/monkeypatch.html#_pytest.monkeypatch.MonkeyPatch.syspath_prepend).</s>

You may prepend a path to `sys.path` list of import locations.  Write a fake `fwlib.py` and include it in your tests, appending the directory as necessary.  Like the other test modules, it needn't be included with the distribution.

After playing with this myself, I couldn't actually figure out how to get the fixture to mock module level imports correctly from the library code. By the time the tests run, the library code was already imported and then it is too late to patch.

However, I can offer a different solution that works: you may inject the name from within `conftest.py`, [which gets imported first](https://docs.pytest.org/en/latest/pythonpath.html).  The subsequent import statement within the code under test will just re-use the object already present in `sys.modules`.

Package structure:

```
$ tree .
.
├── conftest.py
├── lib
│   └── my_lib.py
└── tests
    └── test_my_lib.py

2 directories, 3 files
```

Contents of files:

```
# conftest.py
import sys

def fwlib_sum(a, b):
    return a + b

module = type(sys)('fwlib')
module.sum = fwlib_sum
sys.modules['fwlib'] = module
```

library file:

```
# lib/my_lib.py
import fwlib

def fw_sum(a, b):
    return fwlib.sum(a, b)
```

test file:

```
# lib/test_my_lib.py
import my_lib

def test_sum():
    assert my_lib.fw_sum(1, 2) == 3
```

Comment: This is excellent, thank you! Could you please clarify the last statement, about needn't it be included with the distribution?

Comment: Presumably you have a `./tests/` subdirectory, that is not packaged up by your `setup.py` file when creating a distribution.  You may create for example `./tests/mocks/fwlib.py` that can be imported during test runs, but it's not distributed with your library.

Comment: Ah, I see. I'll wait a bit for other answers to come (however unlikely) and accept your soon. Thanks again!

Comment: Does anyone know how to do this when the import is like "from <module> import <function>"?

Comment: @Neosapien The same approach still works. Inject in `sys.modules` the <module> name.

Comment: And what about restoring the module after we change the module in conftest.py?

Comment: @sergzach Not really needed. Once pytest exits, the Python process exits.

Comment: @wim You may have many other tests which conflict with the action of changing module globally.

Comment: @sergzach Hmm, maybe in that case you would need to make a fixture which injects to sys.modules and then undoes it at teardown.  It will be tricky, though, because you may not be able to import the library code at the top of the test module (the important would need to be delayed until after the patch was applied).

Comment: You could inject a wrapper module that'll redirect all calls, classes, etc at runtime based on a flag. This will still be a bit tricky for when specific classes are imported directly (as you'll need to create class wrappers too)

Answer (score 7):

Just to provide a little more details to @wim's good answer, you can use it with submodules too, like so:

```
import sys
module = type(sys)("my_module_name")
module.submodule = type(sys)("my_submodule_name")
module.submodule.something = sommething
sys.modules["my_module_name"] = module
sys.modules["my_module_name.my_submodule_name"] = module.submodule
```

Answer (score 2):

Also, based on @Itération's answer, I found you can also use fixtures like so to avoid polluting all tests:

```py
# conftest.py
@pytest.fixture()
def mock_lib_installed():
    def lib_func():
        print("lib_func called")

    module = type(sys)("my_module_name")
    module.submodule = type(sys)("submodule")
    module.submodule.lib_func = lib_func
    sys.modules["my_module_name"] = module
    sys.modules["my_module_name.submodule"] = module.submodule

    yield

    del sys.modules["my_module_name"]
    del sys.modules["my_module_name.submodule"]
```

Comment: Note that this will only work if the module is imported while running the test. If it is imported at the top of the file like normal, then the fixture won't be in place when the import happens, and if the real module is not available (as is the case in this question), then it will fail