# Mocking an import and some simple attributes

Tags: python, mocking

I have a package that's imported in my code that I'd like to mock, since I'm developing it in an environment where that package is not available. I get the impression I should be able to do this easily with `mock`, but have not used it before. In my calling script I put at the top

```
import sys
sys.modules['packageneeded'] = mock.MagicMock()
```

and this fixed my downstream errors when importing the package `packageneeded`. However, I also need to be able to access some attributes downstream, such as `packageneeded.__version__`. How do I define these attributes in my calling script (or a separate file, if need be).

Comment: Related:  [Mocking a module import in pytest](https://stackoverflow.com/q/43162722/674039)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can initialize the `MagicMock` object with additional attributes by passing them as keyword arguments to the constructor:

```
sys.modules['packageneeded'] = mock.MagicMock(__version__='1.2.3')
```

Comment: That worked perfectly, thanks. I figured it was something simple.