# mock pty / termios on windows tests

Tags: python, python-3.x, windows, termios, python-unittest.mock

I am developing an application that it's meant to be run on linux, and relies on `pty` and `termios` modules (I don't think it's important, but I'm writing some DAGs on Airflow).
I use a windows workstation.
I would like to run the unit tests on my local machine, and I'm trying to use `unittest.mock.patch` to prevent the import of the (non existent on my OS) modules.

Still, I have problems, and I don't know how to setup the import to avoid errors.

a minimal example is

lib.py

```py
import termios
class C: ...
```

foo.py

```py
from lib import C
def bar(): ...
```

test_foo.py

```py
import foo

def test_foo_bar():
    assert foo.bar() == ...
```

what "magic" should I write in test_foo to avoid the error

```
>pytest test_foo.py
============================================================================================ test session starts =============================================================================================
platform win32 -- Python 3.7.9, pytest-7.0.1, pluggy-1.0.0
rootdir: C:\Users\vito.detullio\Desktop\workspace-srm-cognitive\be-airflow-dags, configfile: pytest.ini
plugins: anyio-3.4.0, cov-3.0.0
collected 0 items / 1 error                                                                                                                                                                                   

=================================================================================================== ERRORS ===================================================================================================
_____________________________________________________________________________________ ERROR collecting delme/test_foo.py _____________________________________________________________________________________
ImportError while importing test module 'C:\Users\vito.detullio\Desktop\workspace-srm-cognitive\be-airflow-dags\delme\test_foo.py'.
Hint: make sure your test modules/packages have valid Python names.
Traceback:
c:\Program Files\Python37\lib\importlib\__init__.py:127: in import_module
    return _bootstrap._gcd_import(name[level:], package, level)
test_foo.py:1: in <module>
    import foo
foo.py:1: in <module>
    from lib import C
lib.py:1: in <module>
    import termios
E   ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'termios'
========================================================================================== short test summary info ===========================================================================================
ERROR test_foo.py
!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!! Interrupted: 1 error during collection !!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!
============================================================================================== 1 error in 0.14s ==============================================================================================
```

Answer (score 0):

You first have to make sure that you don't import the non-existing module via a top-level import. If you import it only locally, you can add some placeholder module to the module cache before doing the import:

```py
import sys
from unittest import mock


def test_foo_bar():
    if "termios" not in sys.modules:
        sys.modules["termios"] = mock.MagicMock()
    import foo
    assert foo.bar() == ...
```

This of course assumes that you don't actually need the module in your test.

Note that you also cannot patch `bar` or something else that lives in that module via a `patch` decorator`, as that would also import the module before you have a chance to patch it, even if it does not directly reference it. You have to do the patching inside the test instead.

Answer (score 0):

I had the same issues with airflow recently. Inspired by [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/48290984/4401979) answer, I resolved mocking all airflow-correlated modules. The idea is to edit the module map using the `sys.modules` dictionary from `sys` module contained in Python Standard Library.
For example, if you need to mock only `task` from `decorators.airflow` module (that is not working on Windows), you can use the following code:

```
airflow_module = type(sys)("airflow")
airflow_module.decorators = type(sys)("decorators")
airflow_module.decorators.task = MagicMock()
sys.modules["airflow"] = airflow_module
sys.modules["airflow.decorators"] = airflow_module.decorators
```

You can mock every `airflow` submodule using this method (that also works for submodules). For example, in my case, I add to `conftest.py` the following code to mock `task`, `get_current_context`, `Variable` and `TriggerRule` from different `airflow` submodules:

```
if platform.system() == 'Windows':
    airflow_module = type(sys)("airflow")
    airflow_module.decorators = type(sys)("decorators")
    airflow_module.operators = type(sys)("operators")
    airflow_module.operators.python = type(sys)("python")
    airflow_module.models = type(sys)("models")
    airflow_module.models.variable = type(sys)("variable")
    airflow_module.utils = type(sys)("utils")
    airflow_module.utils.trigger_rule = type(sys)("trigger_rule")

    airflow_module.decorators.task = MagicMock()
    airflow_module.operators.python.get_current_context = MagicMock()
    airflow_module.models.variable.Variable = MagicMock()
    airflow_module.utils.trigger_rule.TriggerRule = MagicMock()

    sys.modules["airflow"] = airflow_module
    sys.modules["airflow.decorators"] = airflow_module.decorators
    sys.modules["airflow.operators"] = airflow_module.operators
    sys.modules["airflow.operators.python"] = airflow_module.operators.python
    sys.modules["airflow.models"] = airflow_module.models
    sys.modules["airflow.models.variable"] = airflow_module.models.variable
    sys.modules["airflow.utils"] = airflow_module.utils
    sys.modules["airflow.utils.trigger_rule"] = airflow_module.utils.trigger_rule
```