# Can you use read_feather without pyarrow package?

Tags: python, pyarrow, feather

I need to load a feather file in `python`, preferably with `pandas`, so I tried to use `read_feather`, but came across the error

```
/pandas/io/feather_format.py", line 21, in _try_import
    raise ImportError("pyarrow is not installed\n\n"
```

And indeed, the codebase I am working in does not have `pyarrow` integrated. When reading https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.read_feather.html, it appears `pyarrow` is needed for certain `dtype` backends, but I am using the `default` settings so I am not sure why it is needed.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

We cannot `read_feather` without `pyarrow` package because `feather IO` functionality that is used in pandas is implemented in `pyarrow`, and thus pandas needs that library to be able to read or write feather files.

```
from pyarrow import feather

pa_table = feather.read_table(
            handles.handle, columns=columns, use_threads=bool(use_threads)
        )
```

---

Even for `dtype_backend == "numpy_nullable"`

```
if dtype_backend == "numpy_nullable":
            from pandas.io._util import _arrow_dtype_mapping

            return pa_table.to_pandas(types_mapper=_arrow_dtype_mapping().get
```

**Link to source code:  https://github.com/pandas-dev/pandas/blob/v2.1.3/pandas/io/feather_format.py#L72-L148**

Comment: I see. Are there other ways to read `feather` files in `python` without the need for `pyarrow`? Alternatively, I can request that `pyarrow` be added to our installation, but wanted to explore other options as well.

Comment: but it's Python, so you can _always_ monkey patch missing functions and modules. So with that in mind, can you? (even if installing pyarrow is by far the better solution =D) Could you just copy the read_feather bits you need and then shim them in place?

Comment: @user1750101 I think we cannot read feather without `pyarrow` coz `feather.read_feather()` , `feather.read_table()`, etc. are all coming from `pyarrow`.

Comment: @Mike'Pomax'Kamermans.. I know very little about monkey patching. If you can show us, we will be grateful.

Comment: E.g. https://stackoverflow.com/a/48290984/740553, where you just "tell python it already knows a module" by, instead of importing, manually creating the binding that importing would normally create. The real issue here would be how much you'd need to monkey patch, because if we dig through `read_feather`, we need `feather`, which is [a lot of code](https://github.com/apache/arrow/blob/main/python/pyarrow/feather.py) that in turn relies on _a lot_ of other code, so realistically you just want to install `pyarrow`.

Comment: Thanks Mike for the detailed comment :)

Comment: @user1750101 was your question answered?