# Creating a mock library if an optional library can't be loaded--an acceptable practice?

Tags: python, python-3.x, mocking

I want to print in Python 3.6 using [colored](https://pypi.org/project/colored/) if that package is available, like so:

```py
print('{}Hello, world!{}'.format(colored.fg(1), colored.attr(0)))
```

However, I want to make `colored` optional if possible, while still printing any text that would optionally be stylized. Simply creating a wrapper function for printing seems inadequate, due to the multiple ways you can use `colored`, such as `colored.stylize()` and adding colors together:

```py
cheerful = colored.fg('cyan') + colored.attr('bold')
print(colored.stylize("Hello, world!", cheerful, colored.attr("underlined"))
```

Although mocking is usually used for testing, **is it acceptable practice to create a mock library to use if the optional library isn't available**? Something like so, in a module called `colored_mock` (mocking as described [in this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41220803/mock-an-entire-module-in-python)):

```py
from unittest.mock import Mock
import sys
import types

module_name = 'mock_colored'
mock_colored = types.ModuleType(module_name)
sys.modules[module_name] = mock_colored

# following the original definition
def stylize(string, styles, reset=True):
    # return the original string so it can be used
    return string

mock_colored.stylize = Mock(name=module_name+'.stylize', side_effect=stylize)

# and so on until most of the module attributes and functions are covered
```

This way I can do:

```py
try:
   import colored
except ImportError:
    from .mock_colored import mock_colored as colored
```

Comment: Why do you want to make this module optional?

Comment: Because the color formatting is purely to make certain words stand out when printed, but I'd rather them print without formatting than not print at all.

Comment: I mean why can't you just install it?

Comment: Because I'm thinking of distributing this code, and might add an option to print with and without styling.

Comment: When distributing your code, you can specify what modules and packages are required for successfull installation of your code. This is a common approach. Like when you run `pip install matplotlib` it installs `numpy` with it.

Comment: Yes, I know this. But this would not be a distribution through PyPi, and again, I want to make `colored`  _optional_. If the user doesn't feel they need it, then everything should print without being stylized.

Answer (score 0):

Using a `Mock` suggests you are testing. If this is your own code, it might be better to have a wrapper for `stylized` plus any other `colored` methods you are importing:

```
colored_imported = False
try:
    import colored
    colored_imported = True
except ImportError: 
    pass

def stylized(string, styles, reset=True):
    if colored_imported:
        return colored.stylized(string, styles, reset=reset)
    else:
        return string
```

This will help spot problems caused by misspelt methods (e.g., `stylised`) or having too few parameters. This approach should also make your code easier to understand and debug.